# How to call mutation on state change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a web app that has multiple components in App.Vue but will show one at a time and I'm keeping track with a variable 'Step' in Store. So something like this:

```html
<div class="hero-body main-content-container">
  <Welcome id="intro" v-if="steps == 1"></Welcome>
  <template v-cloak>
    <Keywords id="keywords" v-if="steps == 2"></Keywords>
    <Ads v-if="steps == 3"></Ads>
  </template>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what best practice is so that I can watch the state of 'Step' and when it reach a certain step I want to call a certain mutation before any of the code that runs within the actual component. I was thinking of using a watch property in the App.vue file but it seems like using a watcher like this isn't a great idea, from the context I've read online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store your `Step` in the store and only change it through actions. Then you have complete control over what happens and when.

For example

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    step: 1,
    // etc
  },
  mutations: {
    incrementStep (state) {
      if (state.step < MAX_STEPS) { // just a precaution
        state.step += 1
      }
    },
    // etc
  },
  actions: {
    nextStep ({ commit, state }) {
      commit('incrementStep')
      if (state.step === A_CERTAIN_STEP) {
        commit('certainMutation')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then your components can dispatch the *"nextStep"* action without having to do anything else.